# Why does calculation of sign of product of two variables use absolute value?

Tags: fortran, netlib

The Netlib library module for the [Brent root-finding function](http://netlib.org/go/zeroin.f) checks that the signs of two variables are different like this:

```
if (fa * (fb/dabs(fb)) .le. 0.0d0) go to 20
...
```

Why would this check include `/dabs(fb)` instead of being simply `(fa*fb) .le. 0.0d0`? I did a quick check with Python and it seems for very large values (+/-1e200) for x and y, where x*y=+/- inf, the comparison x*y<= 0 still works correctly.

Comment: Q: If all you're interested in is the sign ... then there's nothing "wrong" with `(fb/dabs(fb))` ("+1/-1").  I'm guessing it just mitigates the risk of overflow?  For historical reasons?

Comment: @paulsm4 It looks like you might be right about mitigating risk of overflow. [This (old) page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4940/6j4m1u7pg/index.html) describes default Fortran behaviour of a floating-point overflow (different for f77 and f90) and trapping exceptions. I guess gcc would have similar options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortran has never specified a function like `signs_differ(x,y)`, so one generally implements such a thing personally.

`x*y<0` (and `x*y.lt.0`) is not asking the same thing as "are x and y of different sign?". While the product of x and y being positive means x and y are the same sign in the (mathematical) real numbers, this is not true for (computational) floating point numbers.

Floating point multiplication `x*y` may overflow, result in a signed infinite value (raising a IEEE flag) with the comparison returning the expected logical value, but that isn't always true. There were many non-IEEE systems and IEEE systems may see that flag being raised and abort (or have some expensive handling diversion). That's totally not the same thing as "do x and y have the same sign?".

`x*(y/dabs(y))` doesn't overflow, is "portable" and is potentially cheaper than `(x/dabs(x))*(y/dabs(y))` - ignoring the issues surrounding `dabs()` and signed zeros.

Modern Fortran has functions such as `sign`, `ieee_copy_sign` and `ieee_signbit` which didn't exist 40 years ago.